# MySQL reject insert `NULL` value in `default null` column

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL reject insert `NULL` value in `default null` column: (column: tid)

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `ww_uid_tid_qid_aid` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qzid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(32) NOT NULL,
  `tid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `wokbits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `update_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `ww_uid_tid_qid_aid`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `qzid_2` (`qzid`,`uid`,`qid`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `ww_uid_tid_qid_aid.tid` (`tid`),
  ADD KEY `qid` (`qid`),
  ADD KEY `aid` (`aid`),
  ADD KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  ADD KEY `qzid` (`qzid`),
  ADD KEY `qid_2` (`qid`,`aid`),
  ADD KEY `status` (`status`),
  ADD KEY `status_2` (`status`,`aid`),
  ADD KEY `qzid_3` (`qzid`,`qid`),
  ADD KEY `wokbits` (`wokbits`),
  ADD KEY `tid` (`tid`,`status`);
```

SQL Query:

```
insert ignore into ww_uid_tid_qid_aid
(id,qzid,uid,tid,qid,aid,status,time,wokbits,create_date,update_date)
values
(142598981,1000110,10006849,NULL,10237838,10237840,1,3.4032369852066,44,now(),now())
```

Error msg:

```
#1048 - Column 'tid' cannot be null
```

Also tried: `DEFAULT`

```
insert ignore into ww_uid_tid_qid_aid
(id,qzid,uid,tid,qid,aid,status,time,wokbits,create_date,update_date)
values
(142598981,1000110,10006849,DEFAULT,10237838,10237840,1,3.4032369852066,44,now(),now())
```

Return same Error msg,

Edit:

table is large, contain 587,702 row

foreign keys:

```
ALTER TABLE `ww_uid_tid_qid_aid`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ww_uid_tid_qid_aid_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`tid`) REFERENCES `tag` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ww_uid_tid_qid_aid_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ww_uid_tid_qid_aid_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`qid`) REFERENCES `question` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ww_uid_tid_qid_aid_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`qzid`) REFERENCES `ww_quiz` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ww_uid_tid_qid_aid_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`qid`,`aid`) REFERENCES `answer_choice` (`question_id`, `id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ww_uid_tid_qid_aid_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`status`,`aid`) REFERENCES `answer_choice` (`is_correct`, `id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ww_uid_tid_qid_aid_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`qzid`,`qid`) REFERENCES `ww_question` (`qzid`, `qid`);
```

Comment: What is the mysql version u are using?

Comment: innodb_version: 5.5.41 @Malinga

Comment: As an aside, note that you have no PRIMARY KEY, which may prove problematic further down the road.

Comment: try not setting a default in create query because its anyway its defaults to null

Comment: I post the rest of create SQL query, Primary key do exist @Strawberry

Comment: Aha. That's the important bit. But actually, in this instance I still cannot replicate this problem... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6249b

Comment: It's large table: rows = 587,702 @Strawberry

Comment: That makes no difference

Comment: Do you have any foreign key constraints on other tables pointing to this one?

Comment: Yes, Post updated with foreign keys @Strawberry

Comment: testing other values with `tid= NULL` accepted by DB, could it be MySQL bug in this version? @Strawberry

Comment: In that scenario, I *think* that the column has to be specifically declared as null - but I'm not sure why, and I might be mistaken. In other words, Bernd's answer is correct, but only by accident!

Comment: One of reason may be the data file corrupted. To test it create another table like it and insert all rows to that. (You can use 'create t2 like t1' syntax). Then insert this row to that table.

Comment: @Msfvtp, will test this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved after applied 'Msfvtp' solution:

```
CREATE TABLE ww_uid_tid_qid_aid_tmp LIKE ww_uid_tid_qid_aid;
INSERT INTO ww_uid_tid_qid_aid_tmp SELECT * FROM ww_uid_tid_qid_aid;
RENAME TABLE ww_uid_tid_qid_aid TO ww_uid_tid_qid_aid_tmp2, ww_uid_tid_qid_aid_tmp To ww_uid_tid_qid_aid;
```

SQL query:

```
insert ignore into ww_uid_tid_qid_aid
(id,qzid,uid,tid,qid,aid,status,time,wokbits,create_date,update_date)
values
(142598981,1000110,10006849,DEFAULT,10237838,10237840,1,3.4032369852066,44,now(),now())
```

work fine,

Comment: Glade I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You not have defined that tid can be NULL. change the CREATE TABLE to:

```
CREATE TABLE `ww_uid_tid_qid_aid` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qzid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(32) NOT NULL,
  `tid` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `qid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `wokbits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `update_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT IGNORE INTO ww_uid_tid_qid_aid
(id,qzid,uid,tid,qid,aid,STATUS,TIME,wokbits,create_date,update_date)
VALUES
(142598981,1000110,10006849,NULL,10237838,10237840,1,3.4032369852066,44,now(),now());
```

**sample to alter the table**

```
ALTER TABLE  `ww_uid_tid_qid_aid`
MODIFY COLUMN `tid`  INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

**EXAMPLE with ALTER TABLE and INSERT**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> CREATE TABLE `ww_uid_tid_qid_aid` (
    ->   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   `qzid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   `uid` int(32) NOT NULL,
    ->   `tid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `qid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   `aid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `time` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
    ->   `wokbits` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   `create_date` datetime NOT NULL,
    ->   `update_date` datetime NOT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.47 sec)

MariaDB [yourschema]>
MariaDB [yourschema]> ALTER TABLE  `ww_uid_tid_qid_aid`
    -> MODIFY COLUMN `tid`  INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [yourschema]>
MariaDB [yourschema]> INSERT IGNORE INTO ww_uid_tid_qid_aid
    -> (id,qzid,uid,tid,qid,aid,STATUS,TIME,wokbits,create_date,update_date)
    -> VALUES
    -> (142598981,1000110,10006849,NULL,10237838,10237840,1,3.4032369852066,44,now(),now())
    -> ;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourschema]> SELECT * FROM ww_uid_tid_qid_aid;
+-----------+---------+----------+------+----------+----------+--------+------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id        | qzid    | uid      | tid  | qid      | aid      | status | time | wokbits | create_date         | update_date         |
+-----------+---------+----------+------+----------+----------+--------+------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 142598981 | 1000110 | 10006849 | NULL | 10237838 | 10237840 |      1 | 3.40 |      44 | 2016-07-03 10:40:38 | 2016-07-03 10:40:38 |
+-----------+---------+----------+------+----------+----------+--------+------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourschema]>
```

Comment: @mwafi - i have add it in my answer

Comment: Same issue after run: ALTER TABLE  `ww_uid_tid_qid_aid` MODIFY COLUMN `tid`  INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL;

Comment: @mwafi - i not understand that. i have add a example of all

Comment: It's large table, could it be the issue: row# 587,702 ?

Comment: So Bernd, are you able to replicate the behaviour that the OP describes?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in both statements:

**Allow NULL:**

Column will store `NULL` as you're trying to do.

**DEFAULT NULL:**

If you want to store NULL, simply don't pass the value of that column.

Now just alter your table:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY tid int(11);
```

It will be NULL when you don't pass the value. Because all columns are Nullable by default.